# Akka-stream, trigger action once I received a number of items?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am looking for an "aggregator" block in akka-streams. For instance a block that waits until it has received 3 strings and then triggers an action - like evaluating the average length - and propagate downstream the result of the action.

The flow would wait to receive three strings, say

```
"hallo"
"boat"
"cat"
```

then evaluate the average length

```
4
```

and send it downstream. What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on requirement but in your particular case you can do

```
Source(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))
  .grouped(3)
  .map { chunk =>
    chunk.sum / 3.0
  }
```

You can do variation of this using `.scan` as well.